# how to send form authenticated using php?

Tags: php, forms, authentication

'm trying problems with this form, as all spam is coming.
does anyone know how I can authenticate using this same form?

thank anyone who can help!

```
    <?php

    $para = "martins.ago@gmail.com";
    $assunto = "Orçamento";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n"; 
    $headers .= "From:Log Materiais <martins.ago@gmail.com>\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST['razaosocial_nome']." <".$_POST['email'].">\r\n";
    mail("martins.ago@gmail.com",$assunto,$corpo,$headers); 

    mail($_POST['email'],$assunto,$corpo,$headers); 
    unset($_SESSION['Carrinho']['Produto']);
    unset($_SESSION['Carrinho']);
?>
<script>
alert("Seu pedido de orçamento foi enviado, em 24 horas entraremos em contato, aguarde.");
window.location = '../home/index.php?orcamento=Sucesso';
</script>
```

Comment: Use `CAPTCHA` -> `reCAPTCHA` to prevent `SPAM`. https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php and for that you need http://www.google.com/recaptcha

Answer (score 0):

Use reCaptcha. See https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php for reCaptcha PHP documentation.